# Debian 10 Mouse lagging

Tags: debian, mouse, bugs, lag

I have installed `Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)` on my 4k laptop. All things are working fine. 4k resolution is also rendering fine only issue is that my mouse is lagging too much. What should I do to remove this lag. 
You can see the lagging in below image.

`Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) / AMD® Oland`

`GNOME: 3.30.2`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check if there is **direct rendering** enabled.

```bsh
glxinfo | grep 'direct rendering'
```

Check also Q&A here:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038271/intel-amd-hybrid-graphics-ubuntu-18-04
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/791249/amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-on-ubuntu-16-04
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME

Comment: direct rendering: Yes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What fixed it for me was switching from Wayland to X11:

- Open `/etc/gdm3/daemon.conf`
- Uncomment the line

  ```
  WaylandEnable=false
  ```
- Reboot